# How can I replace all but certain regex patterns in a string?

Tags: regex

How do I make a regex to take a string of names and title case all names in it except for the following patterns, which should be left alone: `[\-\ ][A-Z][a-z]{1,2}[A-Z]` and `[\-\ ][v][ao][n]` for use in JavaScript?

That is, ignore `McD`, `MacD`, `-McD`, `-MacD`, `von` and `van`?  That is, I want to "fix" names typed in in jumbled case, like `LaToNYA von fRANKENSTEIN McDONALD-MacINTOSH` to be `LaTonya von Frankenstein McDonald-MacIntosh`.

I use the following for "title casing" (capitalizing the first letter of each name and lower casing the rest of the name):

```
name = name.replace(/\b\w+/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
```

This, when applied to the name above would result in `Latonya Von Frankenstein Mcdonald-Macintosh`, which is not desirable, especially if the person entering their name typed `LaTonya`, `von`, `McDonald` and `MacIntosh` and it is changed against their wishes.  How can I adjust my replace to leave the patterns given as regex above alone (if the user types `latonya`, `MACDONALD`, or `VON`, then I have no problem changing to `Latonya`, `Macdonald`, or `Von`)?

Comment: Should add the JavaScript tag as well.

Comment: What does the dash `-` have to do with it ? Also, `\w` words don't include the dash. How can you tell where a name ends/begins ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```js
var name = "LaToNYA von fRANKENSTEIN McDONALD-MacINTOSH";
var expected = "LaTonya von Frankenstein McDonald-MacIntosh";
name = name.replace(/\b(v[ao]n|[A-Z][a-z]{1,2}[A-Z])?(\w*)/g, function($0,$1,$2) {
   return $1 ? $1 + $2.toLowerCase() : 
     $0.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + 
       ($0.length > 1 ? $0.substr(1).toLowerCase() : "");
 });
console.log(name, " => " , (expected === name ? "identical" : "different"));
```

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(v[ao]n|[A-Z][a-z]{1,2}[A-Z])?` - Group 1 capturing one or zero occurrences of

  - `v[ao]n` - `von` or `van`
  - `|` - or
  - `[A-Z][a-z]{1,2}[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter, 1 or 2 lowercase ones, and an uppercase ASCII letter again
- `(\w*)` - Group 2 capturing zero or more word chars

The `$0,$1,$2` stand for the whole match, Group 1 and Group 2 values.

Comment: Wiktor, this is perfect!  You are a regex guru!  You should post this to regexlib.com, as I'm sure this would be very useful to a lot of people.